# Is it possible to expand a macro into two piece of data with different types

Tags: c++, macros

**UPDATE**

It seems that the original question is not that clear, so I made another example to specify what I need.

```
#define RPC_FUNC(X) &X,???   // I don't know how...

class Test {
public:
    static void func(int a) {}
};


int main()
{
    const auto ptr1 = std::make_pair(&Test::func, "Test::func");
    // const auto ptr2 = std::make_pair(RPC_FUNC(Test::func));
    // ptr2.first(123);  // this should call the function Test::func
    // std::cout << ptr2.second; // this should print the string "Test::func"
    
    return 0;
}
```

How to define the macro `RPC_FUNC` to make this code work? Meaning that I want to make `ptr1` and `ptr2` exactly the same.

**ORIGINAL**

I want to do a piece of code like this:

```
template<typename F> // F is the type of some functions
void func(F f, const std::string& funcMark) {
    // do something
}
```

I want to pass a non-static member function and a string into the function `func`.

Sometimes, the second parameter is just the name of the first one. Let's see an example:

```
namespace sp {
class Test {
public:
    void doJob() {}
};
}

func(&sp::Test::doJob, "doJob");
```

What I'm trying to do is to do the call above like this: `func(MY_MARCO(sp::Test::doJob))`.

Meaning that, the macro `MY_MACRO` should do expand its parameter `sp::Test::doJob` into `&sp::Test::doJob, "doJob"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification what the macro should precisely do is dim. The stringizing operator # can turn macro argument into string literal:

```
// example code what it does
#include <iostream>

#define YOUR_MACRO(X) X() << " from " << #X "()"

int foo() { return 42; }

int main() { std::cout << YOUR_MACRO(foo) << std::endl; }
```

That outputs

> 42 from foo()

Turning string literal into `std::string` is also trivial:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define YOUR_MACRO(X) X() << " from " << std::string(#X "()")

int foo() { return 42; }

int main() { std::cout << YOUR_MACRO(foo) << std::endl; }
```

Works same. So where are you stuck?

**UPDATE**:

Specification is now lot better! But ... it
is basically same what I already posted that you should use stringizing operator # in macro:

```
#include <iostream>

#define RPC_FUNC(X) &X, #X

class Test {
public:
    static void func(int a) {
        std::cout << "called Test::func(" << a << ")" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    const auto ptr1 = std::make_pair(&Test::func, "Test::func"); // gets warning about unused variable
    const auto ptr2 = std::make_pair(RPC_FUNC(Test::func));
    ptr2.first(123);  // prints "called Test::func(123)"
    std::cout << ptr2.second << std::endl; // prints "Test::func"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just re-edit my question. Could you please re-read it? I don't think your current solution can help me.

Comment: Updated. But it is all same what I posted (at least for my mind)?

Comment: No man. You must keep `std::make_pair` there. Do not move it into the macro...

Comment: Are you being captious? That made no difference if it was inside macro or outside.

Comment: Nop. You can read my original question again. In my real code, I called the function like this: `func(&sp::Test::doJob, "doJob", ...)`. The part `...` is variadic. It works but The first and the second parameters are kind of boring because they are always together: one is the function name and the other is its name with string type. That's why I want to make a macro to wrap the two parameters. I don't want to touch the other parts. I want to call it like this: `func(MY_MACRO(sp::Test::doJob), ...)`

Comment: I pick your answer because with its help, I just have figured it out: `#define MY_MACRO(FUNC) #FUNC, &FUNC,`.